# Registry key for disabling Sharepoint integration in MS Office 2013

Tags: office-integration

There is a registry key named something like "DisableSharepointIntegration" for MS Office 2013. However, all my attempts to google the key were unsuccessful. What is the name of the key and where is it placed?

Comment: I have found something:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\Common\WebIntegration
DWORD = WebIntegrationEnabled
Value = 0` 
However, as far as I remember, there is something similar for sharepoint integration.

Answer (score 1):

The following registry will disable SharePoint in all office applications

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Internet\UseOnlineContent

[This TechNet question](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4723f71c-9842-465c-927b-a1d566518433/disable-sharepoint-integration-in-word-2013?forum=officeitpro) has a lot more information on the subject.

Comment: i have got office 2013 installed but that path is not existing after 15.0. have you verified this answer practically ?

Comment: @kesava I have a group policy that won't let me check this however I assure you it's still valid in Office 2013, here's another source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3039000

Comment: I know the UseOnlineContent and SignInOptions keys. But there is another key called like DisableSharepointIntegration. I have used it a year ago, but unfortunately now I can find no info on it.